# Получение метки диска в Linux

Tags: gcc, c, linux

Как в Линуксе  из программы на С узнать метку диска?

Answer (score 1):

Разберите вывод fdisk -l

Из Си-программы можно через popen();

Comment: Это как-то некошерно. Должно быть другое решение. Эти же программы  узнают метку на низком уровне.

Comment: Они знают структуры заголовка (в первых блоках) диска и читают их по raw device. Ищите эти структуры. Далее open(); read()...

Comment: Можете указать какой-нибудь источник информации? С CD я уже разобрался. А вот с жесткими дисками - не могу найти.

Comment: Подозреваю, что лучший источник fdisk.c из исходников линукса.

Comment: Да, чувствую, придется копаться в исходниках

Comment: А что собственно не устраивает в разборе вывода ? Тут один большой плюс с поддержкой своей программы. fdisk будет при необходимости меняться не Вами. На затраты ресурсов компьютера в подобном случае можно не смотреть.

Answer (score 0):

1. Для Ext2/3

1.1.
Устанавливаем e2fsprogs, если они
не установлены:

`# apt-get install e2fsprogs`

1.2. Устанавливаем
метку диска:

`# e2label /dev/sda1 new_label`

1. Для ReiserFS
   2.1.
   Устанавливаем reiserfsprogs, если они
   не установлены:

`# apt-get install reiserfsprogs`

2.2. Устанавливаем
метку диска:

`# reiserfstune -l new_label /dev/sda1`

1. Для XFS
   3.1.
   Устанавливаем xfsprogs, если они не
   установлены:

`# apt-get install xfsprogs`

3.2. Устанавливаем
метку диска:

`# xfs_admin -l new_label /dev/sda1`

1. Для JFS
   4.1.
   Устанавливаем jfsutils, если они не
   установлены:

`# apt-get install jfsutils`

4.2. Устанавливаем
метку диска:

`# jfs_tune -L new_label /dev/sda1`

1. Для Fat32
   5.1.
   Устанавливаем mtools, если они не
   установлены:

`# apt-get install mtools`

`# echo`

`mtools_skip_check=1 >> ~/.mtoolsrc`

5.2. Устанавливаем
метку диска:

`# mlabel -i /dev/sda1 ::new_label`

1. Для NTFS
   6.1.
   Устанавливаем ntfsprogs, если они
   не установлены:

`# apt-get install ntfsprogs`

6.2. Устанавливаем
метку диска:

`# ntfslabel /dev/sda1 new_label`

Comment: Нужно другое. Как узнать изнутри программы, каким системным вызовом, с какими параметрами? Читай вопрос внимательнее.

Comment: <b>ToshkaSH</b> У людей кагбы все ок со зрением, зачем такими буквами то?О_о

Answer (score 0):

Утилита `lsblk` из пакета `util-linux`.

```
lsblk -f
lsblk -o label
```